# how to configure nginx with magento on ubuntu localhost

Tags: magento, ubuntu, nginx, localhost

i need to install magento 1.8 and 1.9 on ubuntu on nginx server.
i created configuration but is not working fine.

i need to create one global configuration files for magento 1.8, magento 1.9

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }

    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        # With php5-fpm:
                try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error messages do you get in your browser or the nginx logs?

Comment: @RustyFluff error is 403 Forbidden
nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state in the comments that you get a 403 forbidden message. There's a number of things that could be causing this. You will find more information on this error by checking the nginx error logs which are by default kept in `/var/log/nginx/*.log`

I'd strongly recommend checking the error logs for further information as it will speed up the process of fixing the issue.

**1. Incorrect web root**

An obvious one but just make sure you have the correct web root set

`$ ls /usr/share/nginx/html`

**2. Directory and File Permissions**

Check your web user (normally www-data on Ubuntu/Debian) is allowed permissions to access the files in the web directory aswerll as the directory itself. Check the permissions by running on terminal:

`$ ls -l /usr/share/nginx/html`

Make sure the files have the right permissions set and aren't, for example, set to root ownership.

Magento has instructions on resetting the file permissions for your Magento install [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions). In summary run the following on the terminal:

`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 pear
chmod 550 mage #for magento 1.5+`